# chrome tab api from VB.net

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I have been tasked with updating a 3 year old VB.net application to add chrome functionality.  I need to query the open tabs from the VB app.  Is this possible or should I study browser actions and handle this via an extension?

Comment: You need to give more information about what you actually need to do. Chrome extensions are very powerful nowadays and you may even be able to replace your VB app with a Chrome standalone app http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I have written an extension to do exactly that and am quite impressed with the power of Chrome extensions.  It is in the store under the title "NoDupTabs"